# Generators of the Augmentation Ideal (Counit Kernel)

Tags: hopf-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

For the Hopf algebra $SL_q(N)$ it is clear that the kernel of the counit contains the ideal generated by the elements $(u^i_i-1)$ and $u^i_j$, for $i \neq j$. However, I cannot seem to arrive at at proof that it is in fact generated by these elements. Does anyone how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just observe that the quotient by the ideal generated by these elements is at most 1-dimensional.

Comment: Why is that so?

Comment: .. and why does that suffice?

Comment: Let $I$ be the ideal of your quantum group $H$ generated by your guys. Every generator is scalar modulo $I$, thus $I$ is at most 1-dimensional. Bingo!! $I$ sits in the kernel of counit and you have inequality on codimensions that allows you to conclude that they are equal.

Comment: Whooops, I meant to say that $H/I$ is at most 1-dimensional.

Comment: Great! Thanks for that. I was trying to formulate a proof using the divisor theorem for polynomials, but your method is alot easier.